# JSON data parse by comma separator by javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this data format.

```
[{"QualID":1,"Qualification":"Van Driver"},{"QualID":3,"Qualification":"Safety Cert"},{"QualID":4,"Qualification":"Welder"}]
```

I need only qualification data with comma separator. How I get that? Thanks !

```
Van Driver, Safety Cert, Welder
```

I'm trying below way but its coming array value.

```
var jsonData = $.getJSON('/Qualification/GetAllQualificationTypesForDropdown', { user: $(USRNAME_CONTROL_ID).val() }, 'json');
            jsonData.done(function (data) {
                var nuarr = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(JSON.parse(nuarr).map(x => x.Qualification));

                            
                        });
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(' ... ').map(x => x.Qualification)`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox , its coming array value. I need string value with comma separator. Thanks !

Comment: _"coming array value"_ correct! If you'd like it to become a string, you could use `.join(', ')`?

Comment: Also, thank you for adding your attempt

Comment: perfect its working. Thanks @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably do something like this:

```js
const values = [{"QualID":1,"Qualification":"Van Driver"},{"QualID":3,"Qualification":"Safety Cert"},{"QualID":4,"Qualification":"Welder"}] 

const result = values.map(({ Qualification }) => Qualification).join(", ")
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer by help of @evolutionxbox

```
var jsonData = $.getJSON('/Qualification/GetAllQualificationTypesForDropdown', { user: $(USRNAME_CONTROL_ID).val() }, 'json');
            jsonData.done(function (data) {

                var nuarr = JSON.stringify(data);
                var jsonstring = JSON.parse(nuarr).map(x => x.Qualification);
                console.log(jsonstring.join(', '));
                           
                        });
```